# Finding value of Quadratic

Tags: quadratics

If the quadratic equations $3x^2+ax+1=0$ and $2x^2+bx+1=0$ have a common root, then the value of $5ab-2a^2-3b^2$ has to be find.

I tried by eliminating the terms but ended with $(2a-b)x=1$. Can you please suggest how to proceed further?

Comment: Perhaps try using the quadratic formula in the first equation to find a value for $x$ in terms of $a$, then plug into the second equation and solve for $b$, then use that value to find $x$ and therefore $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common root, $r$, is also root of 
\begin{align*}
3x^2+ax+1-(2x^2+bx+1)&=0\\
x^2+(a-b)x&=0\\
x(x+a-b)&=0
\end{align*}

The root cannot be $zero$, so we get $r=b-a$ as the common root.

Also, the common root is a root of
\begin{align*}
2(3x^2+ax+1)-3(2x^2+bx+1)&=0\\
(2a-3b)x-1&=0\\
x&=\frac1{2a-3b}\implies r=\frac1{2a-3b}
\end{align*}

Now,
\begin{align*}
5ab-2a^2-3b^2&=(b-a)(2a-3b)\\
&=r\left(\frac1r\right)\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The common root is where two curves of functions $y_1=3x^2+ax+1$ and $y_2=2x^2+bx+1$ intersect; so we may write:

$3x^2+ax+1=2x^2+bx+1$  ⇒  $x^2 +(a-b)x=0$   ⇒  $ x[x+(a-b)]=0$

$x=0$ is not acceptable

$x= b-a$ can be a solution; plugging this in one of equations we get:

$3(b-a)^2 +a(b-a) +1=0$

Reducing this relation we get:

$5ab -2a^2-3b^2=1$